# Adding a loading screen to flutter while fetching data from firestore

Tags: flutter

I wan't to add a loading screen t my flutter app when it's processing the data using the asyn but i am limited and don't know where to start from and this is my database.dart file which handles the firestore connections and configurations. Help me where can i add a function inside the DatabaseService which will be showing the loading screen and then after the async is done it displays the 'homepage' text.
Database.dart:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/models/words.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  //cloud databse colection  for words

  final CollectionReference wordsCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('words');

  Future insertData(String word, String english_translation,
      String bemba_translation, String user_id, DateTime date_posted) async {
    return await wordsCollection.document().setData({
      'word': word,
      'english_translation': english_translation,
      'bemba_translation': bemba_translation,
      'user_id': user_id,
      'date_posted': date_posted
    });
  }

  //words list from snappshots

  List<Words> _wordsFromSnapShots(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Words(
        word: doc.data['word'],
        englishTranslation: doc.data['english_translation'],
        bembaTranslation: doc.data['bemba_translation'],
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  //Stream snapshots

  Stream<List<Words>> get words {
    // This forces an ordering on the documents in the collection
    return wordsCollection.orderBy('word').snapshots().map(_wordsFromSnapShots);
  }
}
```

My homepage
logged_home.dart:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/main/about.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/models/words.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/screens/author/profile_page.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/screens/home/words_list.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/screens/wrapper.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/services/auth.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/services/database.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/shared/app_bar.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    
    class LoggedInUserHome extends StatelessWidget {
      final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamProvider<List<Words>>.value(
          value: DatabaseService().words,
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[10],
            appBar: LoggedBar(),
            drawer: Drawer(
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: <Widget>[
                  DrawerHeader(
                    child: Text(
                      'Kopalationary Menu',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green[800],
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Home'),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Wrapper()));
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      'My profile',
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfilePage()));
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Logout'),
                    onTap: () async {
                      dynamic result = await _auth.logoutUser();
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      'About',
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => About()),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            body: WordsList(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a StreamBuilder for this. An example might look something like this. You pass a stream into the builder and handle whatever the state of the stream is inside of the builder by looking at the snapshot. If it has an data, you show the content for the data otherwise you show a loading screen or an error screen if there was an error while retrieving the data.

```
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  Stream<List<Words>> wordStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    wordStream = DatabaseService().words;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Words>>(
      stream: wordStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return ErrorWidget();
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ContentWidget(snapshot.data);
        } else {
          return LoadingWidget();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

There are some other connectionStates on the snapshot, that you might want to handle, but this handles the standard cases.

Comment: Where is this coming from  wordStream = DatabaseService.words;

Comment: Well, from the DatabaseService class you implemented yourself.

Comment: What kind of an error? You might have to call the function to retrieve your Stream in another way. In the code I focussed on how one would use a StreamBuilder to show a loading screen based on the fact that your implementation provides as stream of data.

Comment: Yes it has worked but it's only going to homepage without showing the loading screen. Help

Comment: OK, i have added it at the bottom of the question

Comment: Am waiting please

Comment: Hey man, I think you could just wrap your Scaffold in the StreamBuilder as seen above. You should get the stream in the StreamBuilder from your StreamProvider. Alternatively, if you don't use your StreamProvider further down in the Widget tree, you don't even need it and can just get the stream directly like DatabaseService().words.

Comment: Am not understanding this. Can you explain it further?